# chosen file is invalid FXML error on pressing scene builder

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

I am making a to do list with Java FXML and scene builder 2.0. Despite repeated tried and trying available sources on net, I am unable to get rid of this error when I double click on FXML file. I have tried every possible way as far as I could but none seems to work for me

[image]

FXML code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.DialogPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextArea?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker?>
<DialogPane 
    fx:controller="todolist.DialogController"   xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
>
    <headerText>
       
    </headerText>
    <content>
        <GridPane vgap="10" hgap="10">
            <Label text="Short Description:" GridPane.rowIndex="0" GridPane.columnIndex="0"/>
            <TextField fx:id="shortDescriptionField" GridPane.rowIndex="0" GridPane.columnIndex="1"/>
            <Label text="Details:" GridPane.rowIndex="1" GridPane.columnIndex="0"/>
            <TextArea fx:id="detailsArea" GridPane.rowIndex="1" GridPane.columnIndex="1"
                        
            />
            <Label text="Deadline:" GridPane.rowIndex="2" GridPane.columnIndex="0"/>
            <DatePicker fx:id="deadlinePicker" GridPane.rowIndex="2" GridPane.columnIndex="1"/>
        </GridPane>
    </content>
</DialogPane>
```

EDIT: on pressing show details:

```
java.io.IOException: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/Users/Pc%20Planet/Desktop/todolist/src/todolist/todoitemdialog.fxml

    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.fxom.FXOMLoader.load(FXOMLoader.java:92)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.fxom.FXOMDocument.<init>(FXOMDocument.java:80)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.fxom.FXOMDocument.<init>(FXOMDocument.java:95)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.editor.EditorController.updateFxomDocument(EditorController.java:2370)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.editor.EditorController.setFxmlTextAndLocation(EditorController.java:655)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.DocumentWindowController.loadFromFile(DocumentWindowController.java:386)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.SceneBuilderApp.performOpenFiles(SceneBuilderApp.java:579)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.SceneBuilderApp.handleOpenFilesAction(SceneBuilderApp.java:447)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.SceneBuilderApp.handleLaunch(SceneBuilderApp.java:427)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.AppPlatform.requestStartGeneric(AppPlatform.java:139)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.AppPlatform.requestStart(AppPlatform.java:106)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.SceneBuilderApp.start(SceneBuilderApp.java:371)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$8.run(LauncherImpl.java:837)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$7.run(PlatformImpl.java:335)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:301)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:298)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6.run(PlatformImpl.java:298)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$300(WinApplication.java:39)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$4$1.run(WinApplication.java:112)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/Users/Pc%20Planet/Desktop/todolist/src/todolist/todoitemdialog.fxml

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2617)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.importClass(FXMLLoader.java:2864)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processImport(FXMLLoader.java:2708)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processProcessingInstruction(FXMLLoader.java:2677)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2517)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2425)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.fxom.FXOMLoader.load(FXOMLoader.java:89)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javafx.scene.control.DialogPane
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:530)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadTypeForPackage(FXMLLoader.java:2932)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadType(FXMLLoader.java:2921)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.importClass(FXMLLoader.java:2862)
    ... 27 more
```

Comment: I changed the tags from javafx-8 and javafx-2 to just javafx as you are obviously not using both javafx-8 and javafx-2 together.  I do advise that you use a modern JavaFX, JDK and JavaFX versions (e.g. 18).   Info on those is at [openjfx.io](https://openjfx.io) and [gluon](https://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/).

Comment: I copied the FXML from your question and it opened SceneBuilder 18 with no change or error reported.

Comment: i just added the message box it gives on pressing show details

Comment: no errors here: scene builder 17.0.0

Answer (score 3):

DialogPane is a class created after the initial JavaFX 2 release and is not present in some early JavaFX versions (and apparently the version backing the SceneBuilder installation you are using).

You should use modern software and tools that support the source files you are trying to use.

It has been validated that your FXML will load without issue on SceneBuilder 17 and 18, which are available from [gluon](https://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/).